# Looking for a movie with a young alien conected to a control room

Tags: story-identification, science

Years ago I watched a science fiction movie about a young alien man connected up to the control room of a spaceship. On board were several earthlings, with one of them being a model of some sort. The alien and one of the girls fall in love, but find themselves in danger. The only way to save themselves is to release the alien from the controls.

Does anyone know this film?

Comment: Roughly speaking, how long ago was "years ago"? Can you recall any names or descriptions of characters? Was it in English? Color? Live-action? Did it seem to be a made-for-TV movie, or a theatrical feature? Even small details may help us find this.